# Send print job to 2 separate printers

Tags: windows, printing

I have a web based POS. We need to be able to print to 2 printers at the same time. 1 printer at the bar and 1 printer in the kitchen. I've been working on a solution for this for days and no luck so far. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Two things - what have you tried? Do you really need identical tickets for bar and kitchen? (for instance, do the kitchen care about drinks orders, whether it was tendered with cash or card, etc.)

Comment: Ideally some free third party software would be great. I have tried a few apps but the are all super expensive for licenses. I just need an exact copy to be sent to both printers for now. I can work out the rest from there as to what they receive on each printer at a later point in time.

Comment: what language are you writing this in? I.e. are you printing this from the client, or server?

Comment: Everything is done through a WAMP server.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get this working by adding a third printer (not connected) which is offline. Then I added the other printer ports, enabled pooling and doubled the print job so it goes to the second printer when the first printer is busy.

Comment: can you explain exactly how you did it? I've developed a system for truck weight scales, also web based, and I need to be able to send the print job to two printers simultaneously. Thanks.